# Selecionando registros para relatório de acordo com mês e ano

Tags: mysql, laravel

Desejo selecionar os registros de acordo com o mês e o ano para o relatório.
Onde ele coletará dinamicamente os registros dos últimos meses e será mostrado na soma.

```
 $ cobrancas = DB :: table ('cobrancas')
 -> join ('usuários', 'users.id', '=', 'cobrancas.id_loja')
 -> join ('clientes', 'clientes.id', '=', 'cobrancas.id_cliente')
 -> groupby (DB :: raw ('YEAR (cobrancas.data_vencimento)'), DB :: raw ('MONTH (cobrancas.data_vencimento)'))
 -> get ();
 $ total_cobrancas = $ cobrancas-> soma ('valor');

 foreach ($ cobrancas como $ cobranca) {
     if ($ cobrancas-> data_vencimento)
         dd ($ cobranca);
 }
```

Esse código está retornando o valor somado, mas apenas 1 por mês, preciso trazer todos de cada mês.
Onde então separarei os últimos 5 meses e passarei a view.

Comment: No caso, você não tem que ignorar a linha do group by na parte do YEAR?

Comment: Seria interessante apresentar o resultado que vem no atributo $cobrancas utilizando algo como dd($cobrancas), e essa o trecho "$cobrancas->soma('valor');" chama um metodo do objeto? ou uma função?